# set time for loader gif

Tags: jquery, gif, loader

I am using the following for animated gif loader.

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
$(window).load(function() {
$(“.loader”).fadeOut(“slow”);
})
</script>
```

This works great, but Im looking to force my gif to stick around for a set time.  I'd like to start with 1 second.  any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: For 1 second after the window.load event fires?

Comment: You're using the wrong quotes here `$(“.loader”)`

Comment: yes this was an issue! thank you. @j08691

Answer (score 1):

By changing the 3000 (milliseconds), you can reduce or increase the start time of the function

---

fade Out after 3s

```js
$(window).load(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){ $('.loader').fadeOut('slow'); }, 3000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="loader" width="300" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/91700/screenshots/3038974/loader.gif" />
```

---

fade in after 1s and fade Out after 3s

```js
$(window).load(function() {
   setTimeout(function(){ $('.loader').fadeIn(); }, 1000);
   setTimeout(function(){ $('.loader').fadeOut('slow'); }, 4000);
})
```

```css
.loader{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="loader"  width="300" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/91700/screenshots/3038974/loader.gif" />
```